# Unable to get value after JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, json, string, jsonparser

I am facing issue while converting the value from below string. Tried to parse JSON but didn't work.

```
const val1 = "{a: '123'}";

console.log(typeof(val1)); // string

const a = JSON.parse(val1); // Gives Error: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1

const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val1)); 
console.log(b); // {a: '123'}
console.log(b.a); // ---> undefined

console.log(typeof(b)); // string -> How?
```

Again if I do, `JSON.parse(b) -> Gives error: Unexpected token a in JSON at position.`

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong

Comment: Try this : `const val1 = "{'a': '123'}";`. `a` should be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Apart from the quotes, the type of quotes matter as well. val1 should be enclosed in single quotes and the json key values in double quotes. So try this: `const val1 = '{"a": "123"}';`

Comment: @LearningEveryday const val1 = '{"a": "123"}'; works. but, I am receiving string in that pattern from server.

Comment: Added an answer with explanation, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
const jsonString = '{"a": "123"}';
const parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(parsedJson.a)
```

the problem is the single quote in your json string, see this https://www.json.org/json-en.html

You can use the following

```
const jsonString1 = '{"a": "123"}';
const jsonString2 = "{\"a\": \"123\"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const val1 = "{a: '123'}";
console.log(typeof(val1)); // string
const a = JSON.parse(val1); // Gives Error:
```

This happens because `val1` here is not a valid json string, as property `a` and its value   inside the object is not wrapped in double quotes. After doing that you can see it works fine:

```js
const val1 = '{"a": "123"}';
console.log(typeof(val1)); // string
const a = JSON.parse(val1); // It works!
console.log( a )
```

---

```
const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val1)); 
console.log(b); // {a: '123'}
console.log(b.a); // ---> undefined
```

`b.a` is `undefined` here because `b` is not actually an object here but string:

```js
const val1 = "{a: '123'}";
const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val1));
console.log(b); // {a: '123'}
console.log(typeof b); // string
console.log(b.a); // ---> undefined
```

This happens because

```
JSON.stringify(val1)
```

converts `"{a: '123'}"` to `""{a: '123'}""`. It simply add double quotes around `val1` as it was already a string.

and using `JSON.parse` on it just removed the double quotes from it and we got back string again.

```js
const val1 = "{a: '123'}";
const val2 = JSON.stringify(val1);
console.log( val2 )   // "{a: '123'}" ... its actually ""{a: '123'}""
console.log( typeof val2 )  // string

const val3 = JSON.parse(val2);
console.log( val3 )   // {a: '123'} ... its actually "{a: '123'}"
console.log( typeof val3 )  // string
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your line #4

```
const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val1));
```

You are trying to parse the result of

```
JSON.stringify("{a: '123'}")
```

That produces a "string inside string".

[image]

As previous answer suggested, make sure your json format is correct.
Use tool like https://jsonlint.com/ to check your json.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code below. Please check as it works.

```js
    const val1 = '{"a": "123"}';

console.log(typeof(val1)); // string

const a = JSON.parse(val1); // a is a json now

const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val1)); //val1 is already is string so no need to do this
console.log(a); // {a: '123'}
console.log(a.a); // ---> changed to a
const c = JSON.parse(b);
console.log(typeof(b)); // string -> Double stringing but converting to json only once so its still a string
console.log(typeof(c)); // Have to do JSON.parse on b to make it a Object again
```